# Access flux fields from another Fluidtypo3 FCE element (flux, fluidcontent, vhs)

Tags: typo3, fluid, flux

I'm trying to access the settings of a Fluidtypo3 FCE element. My FCE is a news article that I want to include in another FCE, which is a slider. The slider only has one field and the configuration is the following:

```
<flux:field.relation
            name="articles"
            label="News-Beitrag"
            multiple="true"
            size="6"
            table="tt_content"
            condition="AND tt_content.pid = {record.pid} AND CType = 'fluidcontent_content' AND colPos = 1 AND sys_language_uid = {record.sys_language_uid}"
            minItems="1"
            maxItems="10"
            renderMode="default"
            />
```

This configuration works, I can select all my news FCE's as a relation. The field `articles` saves the uid's of all referenced FCE's. Now I am trying to use these uid's to receive the content. Right now my code is the following:

```
<f:section name="Main">

    <f:if condition="{articles}">

        {v:iterator.explode(content: '{articles}', glue: ",", as: 'articles')}

        {v:content.get(contentUids: "{articles}", render: 0) -> v:variable.set(name: 'slides')}

        <f:for each="{slides}" as="element">
        </f:for>

    </f:if>

</f:section>
```

The `<v:content.get>` ViewHelper gets the tt_content record as it is recorded in the database. The flux settings are stored in XML-Format in the field `pi_flexform`. I am trying to access those specific flux settings one by one and not just the whole `pi_flexform` field in xml format.

I've looked for ViewHelpers that can convert XML to an Array and tried many other things, but nothing worked for me. I am grateful for any ideas how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`<flux:form.data>`](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master/Form/DataViewHelper.html) is the Viewhelper you seek. You can use it like this:

```
<f:for each="{slides}" as="element">
    <flux:form.data table="tt_content" field="pi_flexform" record="{element}" as="flexformData">
        <!-- Do stuff with flexformData -->
    </flux:form.data>
</f:for>
```

Comment: You are my hero! I've been searching for hours and even tried that viewhelper, but obviously didn't use it the right way. I had to add `table="tt_content"` to the `<flux:form.data>` Viewhelper though, since it is a required attribute.

Comment: Thanks, added the missing parameter :-)